# Hive unordered pairs function

Tags: hive

Is it possible to generate unordered pairs in Hive (similar to Pig Unordered Pairs function?) Does this function exist anywhere?

Ideally I would like to be able to pass in a table such as :

```
select * from mytable

array_1 
["A","B","C"]
```

and get back

```
select unorderedPairs(array_1) from mytable


["A",B"]
["B","C"]
["C","A"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function. In Hive this would be called a User Defined Table Generating Function. Here are the built-in UDTF's:

- inline(ARRAY)
  Explodes an array of structs into a table. (As of Hive 0.10.)
  Array Type
- explode(array a)
  For each element in a, generates a row containing that element.
  tuple
- json_tuple(jsonStr, k1, k2, ...)
  Takes a set of names (keys) and a JSON string, and returns a tuple of values. This is a more efficient version of the get_json_object UDF because it can get multiple keys with just one call.
  tuple
- parse_url_tuple(url, p1, p2, ...)
  This is similar to the parse_url() UDF but can extract multiple parts at once out of a URL. Valid part names are: HOST, PATH, QUERY, REF, PROTOCOL, AUTHORITY, FILE, USERINFO, QUERY:.
  N rows
- posexplode(ARRAY)
  Behaves like explode for arrays, but includes the position of items in the original array by returning a tuple of (pos, value). (As of Hive 0.13.0.)
- stack(INT n, v_1, v_2, ..., v_k)
  Breaks up v_1, ..., v_k into n rows. Each row will have k/n columns. n must be constant.